# iOS: difference between MDM and Over-the-Air Profile Delivery and Configuration

Tags: ios, mobile, configuration

I'm looking for solutions for device management on iOS universe and I've found two approaches: Mobile Device Management (http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/it-center/deployment-mdm.html) and Over-the-Air Profile Delivery and Configuration (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html).
However, I can't seem to find a difference between both approaches or if, in practice, both are the same.
Can someone clarify this topic?

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Device Management is a broader term which includes configuration management, application management etc. Whereas OTA deployment is a mechanism on how the configuration profile is being send down to the device. The alternatives for OTA profile delivery are,

1. Using IPCU
2. Email
3. Making profile available in web location

Answer (score 2):

Over-the-Air Profile Delivery is used to deliver a configuration profile on an iOS device. While MDM uses that mechanism to deliver its initial (MDM configuration) payload, the resemblance ends there. MDM can deliver configuration profiles as well, but it can do A LOT more.

For instance:

- removing profiles
- installing and removing applications
- locking/wiping the device
- etc.