# What is the difference between Mobile Device Management and Over The Air Method?

Tags: ios, mdm, ota

I have gone through a number of questions regarding the `mobile device management and Over the Air method` but I did not get what is the exact difference between the two.What I got from study that OTA was used previously and was replaced by more effective MDM.What I want to know is what was the need of **MDM** when **OTA** was there or Why OTA was replaced.Can I use the OTA server for MDM installation?

I have gone through a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841645/ios-difference-between-mdm-and-over-the-air-profile-delivery-and-configuration) question but didn't get a satisfying answer so I wanted to ask for a fresh one.

Comment: Please leave a comment with down vote . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OTA was old way and it was limited:

- It allowed only manual installation of configuration profiles (you can't automatically push any new profiles
- It was limited to profiles only (no commands)

MDM is the new way. It allows

- Automatic installation/upgrade/removal of profiles (when your device is enrolled already)
- You can issue commands (like Wipe)

A lot of MDM vendors use OTA to bootstrap MDM (install a configuration profile with MDM payload to a device) and later on they use MDM for the rest of device management.

**Update 1**

Generally OTA is used for couple of reasons:
a) To authenticate user
b) To authenticate device (that a client is iOS based device)
c) To distribute initial MDM profile

Item a) and c) could be easily done without OTA. You can have just a web server which will use some form of user authenticate and will return MDM profile.

And I don't think that you can solve b) outside of OTA.

If you go with OTA, you will have to implement all three phases. Phase 1 is most flexible (you can implement a user authentication different ways). Phase 2 and 3 are very strict.

Comment: Thanks for response..As you said a lot of MDM Vendors use OTA for installation and later use MDM.Is there any way possible so that we don't use OTA at all and use only MDM and if we use OTA should we use all three phases of OTA installation as defined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html and then MDM requests as defined in apple MDM documentation.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer victor.Can you please tell me how server sends command to the device and how device comes to know that command is executed and reverts back to the server with acknowledgement plist.A brief code related discussion will be really helpful.

Comment: @YogeeshHT I would recommend to read official MDM documentation. It has good description of basic mechanics of how commands are sent and acknowledged.

Comment: For profile installation I am using OTA.I have gone through apple documentation for OTA https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html. In the implementation of OTA we have three sections. Lets take first  Authentication which has four steps.All these steps give link to some code (in pdf) that I don’t understand.Should I just need to copy paste as it is or should I need to learn about that coding since I don’t understand how code flows there.So basically can you please guide about the approach for OTA.

Comment: What is the code in PDF? Can you give a link? Also, what do you don't understand (can you please be more specific)?

Comment: In the OTA documentation in the authentication phase see the first point i.e.  1. The user visits the root URL (/) and gets a welcome message. This message is provided by the handler described in “Welcome Page (/) URL Handler” (page 17). 
the double code Welcome Page Url Handler is a hyper link and it takes to the code below.

Comment: world.mount_proc("/") { |req, res|
      res['Content-Type'] = "text/html"
      res.body = <<WELCOME_MESSAGE
  <style>body { margin:40px 40px;font-family:Helvetica;}h1 { font-size:80px; }p { font-size:60px; }a { text-decoration:none; }</style<h1 >ACME Inc. Profile Service</h1><p>If you had to accept the certificate accessing this page, you should
  download the <a href="/CA">root certificate</a> and install it so it becomes
  trusted. <p>We are using a self-signed
  certificate here, for production it should be issued by a known CA. <p>After that, go ahead and <a href="/enroll">enroll</a>

Comment: The below codes are the HTML/CSS tags but first line codes are some thing I don’t understand.There is same case with point 2. 1. “Root Certificate (/CA) URL Handler” that also redirects to some piece of code. So can you please tell me whats that code is all about?

Comment: One more thing in  Certificate Enrollment (Phase 2) part it is written that from the device side no user interaction is allowed and is done automatically.So after the Phase 1 what are the things that is automatically done from the device side and if it is automatically done and server comes to know about it for further steps.

Comment: The code world.mount_proc("/") makes sure that if a user access root web page ("/'), it will be handled by a following block. I would recommend to get a Ruby book and browse through first 3-4 chapter and you will be able to understand provided examples.